# Bootstrap 4 - Checkbox al pulsar uno se pulsa el otro

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Al utilizar los "checkbox" de bootstrap. Si se duplican para tener más de uno. Al clicar uno, se quedan clicados los dos. ¿Por qué? Parece que algún código javascript los activa utilizando su id o name, ¿o algo así? ¿Cómo se debe hacer para utilizar varios checkbox con bootstrap y cada uno de ellos funcione de forma independiente?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container mt-3">

  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck" name="example1">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Custom checkbox</label>
      <br>
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck" name="example1">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Custom checkbox</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

primero que nada, te recomiendo que leas la [documentación de bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios-1) que es simplemente espectacular, con pegarle una leida evitarás este tipo de problemas!

En tu código tenes 3 problemas.

1. Los ID deben ser únicos en HTML/CSS/JS
2. El Atributo name (en caso de ser un `checkbox`) también suele ser único
3. La estructura de tu checkbox no se corresponde a la de la [documentación de Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios-1)

**¿Cómo solucionarlo?**

Cambiando el `ID` y el `Name` de uno de los `checkbox` y separarlos en distintos `div.custom-control.custom-checkbox`

Por ejemplo

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="container mt-3">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-0">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck" name="example1">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Custom checkbox</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck2" name="example2">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">Custom checkbox</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: No estoy muy de acuerdo en que el `name` debe ser único ya que son `checkbox`. El caso podría ser una variable arreglo con distintos valores, por ejemplo, `<input type="checkbox" name="suscribe[]" value="noticias"/> etc.`

Comment: @Marcos ahí corregí la palabra, el *debe* era incorrecto, pero creo que si *suele* serlo, gracias por la corrección!